# Best way to maintain multiple shared scripts to be deployed across multiple DB servers?

Tags: shell-script, cron, github

We are in the build phase where we have set of cron jobs running on DB servers. These scripts are being changed constantly. These scripts are supposed to be same across all the other DB servers as well, the way the team does it now - is copy the updated script to all the other servers. We need to eventually come up with a sustainable way to do this.

Shared mountpoint has been ruled out by security team. They want us to explore github. I was thinking, Lets say Server A has the new updated script, Using the github command line upload the modified script to github. Is there a feature where we can sync the changed code to other unix servers like Server B, C etc?

RD

Comment: Have each server download the scripts from github, via a regular cron job ?

Comment: First, decide if you want a "push" architecture (someone tells all the servers they need to update the script), or a "pull" architecture (servers regularly download the script, e.g. from github). Also, think about how the DB servers are normally administered, and how it would integrate with this administration.

Comment: I agree with Dirkt on thinking about administration. My knee-jerk reaction was some kind of cfg management software like ansible, but that might not fit in your overall style of administration.

Comment: Thanks Dirkt, I would say a push architecture. Can this be achieved via github? Sorry I'm extremely new to github.

Comment: `ansible` and other config management tools are a good fit for a push-based approach

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick and helpful responses  much appreciated. I'll try out ansible.